# How can i distribute a list of allowed CAs in a local network?

Tags: certificate-authority

I have a network with different OSs (Windows, macOS, iOS, Linux) and browsers. I would like to centrally manage the list of trusted Certificate Authorities on all clients/browsers. And I'd like to avoid having to manage the list CA manually on each client. Is there any OS-agnostic way to distribute the list of valid CAs to the clients, either through service discovery (have a service that announces "Hey, get your CA list here") or by a OS setting that triggers the clients to pull the list? Windows Active Directory Certificate Services seems to do this, but I'd rather use an Open Source solution.

Comment: There is no way, because each client type uses its own trust store implementation. As the result, OS-agnostic tool cannot exist.

Comment: No. Each browser has their own implementation, except for Internet Explorer, which uses the operating system certificate store. Windows and Linux, also different implementations. The Windows functionality also is not related to Active Directory Certificate Services, it's a core function of the operating system to dynamically check for and download CA certificates, from either the public or internally published location. So really what you are looking for is something that functions exactly like Windows, but isn't Windows.